# Exclude TypeScript files from Web Publish VS 2015

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core

Is there are any way to exclude the TypeScript files on web publish ? 
becouse we do not need to publish those files

- my TS files locate on the wwwroot

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true

  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"

  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do Web Publish the `dotnet publish` is called to gather the files to publish to a temporary folder. And dotnet publish by default uses `project.json` file as configuration source.

Look into `publishOptions` section in `project.json`. There you can specify "exclude" and ""excludeFiles" subsections. Form "Structure to include/exclude files" [part of documentation](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/175#include-structure):

> **"exclude"** string/string[]
>
> A list of file globbing patterns for files to exclude. The exclude patterns have higher priority than the include patterns, hence a file found in both will be excluded. The patterns are rooted at the project folder. Defaults to none.
>
> **"excludeFiles"** string/string[]
>
> A list of file paths to exclude. The paths are rooted at the project folder. This list has a higher priority than globbing patterns and the include paths, hence a file found in all will be excluded. Defaults to none.